# Presented UITableView is scrolling horizontally on iPhone 6/6s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

With this code I'm presenting a blurred `UITableViewController` on another controller but the `UITableView` can be scrolled from left to right like a scroll view. This problem is only happening on the iPhone 6/6s Plus (simulator and real device).

```
LoginTableViewController *contributeViewController = [[LoginTableViewController alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:[UIHelpers blurredViewController:contributeViewController withFrame:contributeViewController.view.frame andBlurEffectStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've tried without the blurred effect but I'm getting the same wrong result.

```
[self presentViewController:contributeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have used 3rd party library of slide menu. Can you provide some code here so I can help you.

Comment: you want to create slide menu?

Comment: may be issue with frame , see viewcontroller autolayout , presentation style

Comment: no, i'm only trying to present a normal UITableView but on bigger screens (iPhone 6/6s Plus) the tableview can be scrolled from left to right and i don't want that.